# If column doesn't contain one of the strings, set to null

Tags: java, mysql

what is the best way to compare the elements of several columns in MySQl table to the elements of string array?
If the elements are not equal then et the element of the current column to null.
Thanks!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: Show us what have you tried ?

Comment: if you mean javascript than java so please retag your question by clicking on edit link.

Comment: I want to set the elements of several columns to null. The requirement is, if the columns don't contain one of the elements of string array, then set those elements in the table to null.  My String array has 7 elements.

 I don't mean javascript, it's java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple update statements to do multiple columns, but the below might help:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn1 = null WHERE myColumn1 NOT IN ('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn2 = null WHERE myColumn2 NOT IN ('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE SOMETABLE SET SOMECOLUMN = null WHERE SOMECOLUMN=array[0] OR SOMECOLUMN=array[1] etc.
```

Comment: it has to be null when it is not equal to none of the array elements.

Comment: sqlSelect = "UPDATE TEST_ATTRIBUTES SET attribute1Name = null WHERE NOT (attribute1Name = 'Size' AND attribute1Name = 'Color'" +  " AND attribute1Name = 'Power' AND attribute1Name = 'Format'" + AND attribute1Name = 'Platform' AND attribute1Name = 'Radius')";

This sets the whole column to null.